# How to connect to HTTPS socket server via SOCKS4 proxy

Tags: python, sockets, pysocks

I am trying to connect to my HTTPS server via SOCKS4 proxy, but it seems like it is not working.

Here is my code:

```py
headers = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: domain.com\r\n\r\n"
import socks
import ssl
conn = socks.socksocket()
conn.set_proxy(socks.SOCKS4, host, port)
conn.connect(("domain.com", 443))
conn = ssl.create_default_context().wrap_socket(conn, server_hostname="domain.com")
conn.send(headers.encode())
```

After I run that code, I checked my website log and nothing happened. But if I change the `connect()` port to 80, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You are `connect()`'ing the `socks` TCP connection to the HTTPS server's TLS port before creating the `ssl` context. Which is fine, however the `SSLSocket` that `wrap_socket()` returns will automatically call `do_handshake()` to negotiate a TLS session only when its `connect()` method is called, which you are bypassing. So, you will need to manually call `do_handshake()` after `wrap_socket()` returns and before calling `send()`, eg:

```py
headers = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: domain.com\r\n\r\n"
import socks
import ssl
conn = socks.socksocket()
conn.set_proxy(socks.SOCKS4, host, port)
conn.connect(("domain.com", 443))
conn = ssl.create_default_context().wrap_socket(conn, server_hostname="domain.com")
conn.do_handshake()
conn.send(headers.encode())
```

Comment: I did that but still not working, in addition, I don't need to do that if i use socks5

Comment: @kenegdane yes, you do need to call `do_handshake()` manually in this situation, regardless of the SOCKS version use. SOCKS will only establish the underlying TCP connection, but HTTPS still requires a TLS handshake afterwards. So, if this code is not working for you, there has to be another problem you are not accounting for. For instance, if the TLS handshake is failing. That may or may not be reported by`do_handshake()`, depending on whether the HTTPS server closes the connection on TLS failure, or whether it waits for an HTTP request to arrive before it then sends back an error reply.